# Autocasting C++ char array as string

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a String class that can be constructed with a char array pointer.  Is there any crazy way, through some magical operator overload, free function, or preprocessor macro to make Python-like syntax work, autocasting a char array literal to a String?  To make this compile:

```
String a = "Foo".substr(1);
```

I suppose a wild pre-compile sed statement would do it, but something within the abilities of clang would be preferred.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this feature? The example code you provided doesn't provide a convincing case

Comment: Purely syntactic sugar.

Comment: If you're even considering "a wild pre-compile `sed` statement", you're already over-thinking this. C++ has conventions. If you flaunt them and invent your own bizarro dialect you're only going to confuse people and break things.

Comment: Isn't that how C++ was invented?

Comment: C++ only makes sense because it has a history, standards, and a large user base. If only Bjarne used it and had never documented it as a standard it would make no sense at all.

Comment: @tadman and `"foo"s.substr(1);` has more sense ;) If all of us think like you we will never have "foreach" `auto` and many more in c++. We are shaping language, don't let language shape you.

Comment: Point taken.  No, I'm not really interested in turning my codebase into some weird dialect that only works because of custom 'extensions'.  That said, I am interested in using features within the modern C++ standards that make the higher level feature code easier to understand and work with.

Comment: @Logman While there's arguably cases for extending and augmenting C++ to make it do new things more efficiently, there's a point where you're over-extending it and turning it into something it isn't. C++ is an unusually unforgiving language, so if your tools help you write better code, by all means, but I've seen too many code-bases consumed by bizarre coding practices that are unable to evolve when C++ fixes the problems those hacks attempted to resolve in the first place.

Comment: @tadman I completely agree that many "new features" may be consider bad. But also I am not brave enough to create a line that will separate bad from good constructs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For C++11 and beyond

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    auto a = "foo"s.substr(1);
}
```

If you wanted to write this for your own `String` class then the way to get the same behavior would be to roll your own user defined string literal, and then do the same

```
#include <cstddef>

class Str {
public:
    explicit Str(const char*) {}
    Str substr(int) { return *this; }
};
Str operator"" _s (const char* input, std::size_t) {
    return Str{input};
}

int main() {
    auto s = "something"_s.substr(1);
}
```

Comment: this will work for those that are using projects that are c++14 or higher

Comment: am I missing something here, isn't OP asking for a user-defined `String` not `std::string`?

Comment: @RyanHaining I'm sure they meant an `std::string` object in C++

Comment: @RyanHaining And a similar approach is possible with user defined objects, you can write your own user defined string literal

Comment: op is asking for some syntactic way to call a string method on a `const char *`... this looks "pretty close" to me

Comment: Actually I meant my own String class, but I wasn't even expecting a "pretty close" answer.

Comment: @Rakurai you can write your own user defined string literal and use that.  It's pretty simple.  You just have to go through documentation for the syntax for doing that.  I'll update my answer

Comment: @Rakurai this might be obvious but you can also just explicitly convert if you are pre-c++14 or don't want to write your own literal operator `String("Foo").substr(1)`

Comment: Meh. Answers to a question tagged C++ in 2017 may assume C++14 for all I care, I wouldn't even complain about C++17 as that's basically done too.

Comment: @BaummitAugen exactly my thoughts

Comment: well that must be pretty awesome to not have to care about code compiling for any standard before the next standard that isn't even final yet...

Comment: @RyanHaining yes, that's what I do currently.  It's perfectly acceptable (and clear), I'm just curious about other ways to go from chars to a String object.

Comment: By the way, the above example for writing your own string literal compiled fine for me with OS X clang and -std=c++11.